# How to limit the row size of a jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row

I am creating a table wherein the data is updated dynamically as and when the user gives input. I dont want the table to contain more than say 10 rows. i.e i wan to limit user input to 10 rows. Any hint on it is appreciated.

here goes my code

```
    class TablePanel extends JPanel {

    private String[] COLUMNS = {"FAMILY MEMBERS", "STAR (NAKSHATRA)"};
       private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(COLUMNS, 0){

        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
           }

       };
       DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){

        public void setHorizontalAlignment(int alignment) {
               alignment = (int) CENTER_ALIGNMENT;
           };

       };
       private JTable table = new JTable(model){
         public void setDefaultRenderer(java.lang.Class<?> columnClass, TableCellRenderer renderer) {
             columnClass= String.class;
             renderer=centerRenderer;
         };  
         public void setBackground(Color bg) {
             bg = Color.yellow;
         };

       };

       public TablePanel() {
          setLayout(new BorderLayout());
          setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 235));
          add(new JScrollPane(table));
       }

       public void addRow(String memb, String star) {
          Object[] row = new Object[2];
          row[0]=memb;
          row[1]=star;
          model.addRow(row);
       }
    }
```

Comment: How are you getting the rows to the table? You can just limit them at input time.

Comment: @Kayaman by onclick button event

Comment: So disable the button when there's 10 rows in the table?

Comment: unrelated: I would suggest you take a step back and read up on some basics of java/OO programming - all this subclassing to restrict object properties to some value is **completely** wrong!

Answer (score 1):

you can place in your addRow method following code:

```
if( model.getRowCount() < YOUR_ROW_LIMIT ){
  the code you already have goes here ...
}
```